# Zend url extra parameters padding issue

Tags: zend-framework

Remove extra parameters padded after url, using zend url function.

When i try to generate url using code given below.

```
$this->_redirect($this->view->url(array('controller'=>'controller','action'=>'index','edit'=>'5')));
```

it adds others parameters from the current url too.

E.g. ../controller/index/edit/5/module/10/id/6

I want to remove extra parameters added to url.

Comment: have you checked docs? http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html `url(array('controller'=>'controller','action'=>'index','edit'=>'5'), null, true)`

Comment: Yes, i tried this too. but parameters added in previous URL using this function are not removed.